# Ajuda com Subprocesso e Thread

Tags: java, thread

Fiz um código que cada chamada de subprocesso é executado por uma Thread diferente, mas que executam o mesmo método com mesmo parâmetros.

Teria como chamar esses subprocessos usando Thread mas passando comandos diferentes?

Exemplo, abrir a calculadora e o cmd, ou programas diferentes e etc.

**Classe Principal do Programa:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public final class UsandoThreadComSubprocessos {

public void execute() {

    ExecutorTask task = new ExecutorTask(); // Criando um objeto tipo ExecutorTask
    Thread executorThread = new Thread(task); //Criando uma thread para executar o Executor
    executorThread.start(); //Executando a Thread

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new UsandoThreadComSubprocessos().execute();//Iniciando uma thread
    new UsandoThreadComSubprocessos().execute();//Iniciando uma Segunda Thread

}
}

class ExecutorTask implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {

    Process process = null; //Criando uma variavel tipo process

    try {

        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c calc"); //Atribuindo um método que chama um subprocesso a uma variavel process
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())); //Capturando o Retorno do processo solicitado
        String line = "";

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { //Lendo o retorno do processo atribuido a variavel line
            System.out.println(line);// Mostrando o resultado na tela

        }

        process.waitFor(); //

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        return;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar um parâmetro no constructor do teu Runnable (ExecutorTask);

```
class ExecutorTask implements Runnable {
    String comando;
```

```
ExecutorTask(String comando) {
    this.comando = comando;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Process process = null; //Criando uma variavel tipo process

    try {

        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c " + comando); //Atribuindo um método que chama um subprocesso a uma variavel process
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())); //Capturando o Retorno do processo solicitado
        String line = "";

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { //Lendo o retorno do processo atribuido a variavel line
            System.out.println(line);// Mostrando o resultado na tela

        }

        process.waitFor(); //

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        return;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Certo , vou implementar aqui .